# PyYAML dump object path

Tags: pyyaml

I have a problem in dumping and loading the YAML files using PyYAML.

I have two separated applications A and B. I would like to dump a YAML file in A, and later load it and use it in B. But the path of the objects seems incorrect.

```
A-folder
    dump.py
B-folder
    the_module.py
    use.py
```

In dump.py, I have code like:

```
yaml.dump(the_class_instance, file_stream, default_flow_style=False)
```

It gives a YAML file:

```
!!python/object:B-folder.the_module.the_class
attribute_0: !!python/long '10'
attribute_1: !!python/long '10'
```

Then I need to use this YAML file in use.py. But I cannot load it correctly as an instance of the_module.the_module.the_class. It says:

```
cannot find module 'B-folder.the_module' (No module named B-folder.the_module)
```

I tried to do the dumping in another module B-folder.adaptor, in dump.py it just calls the methods in B-folder.adaptor, but it still gives the same result.

How to deal with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here isn't actually with PyYAML, it's with Python's module loading.

In A, I'm assuming that you're importing the_module as part of the B-folder package, either with `import B-folder.the_module` or `from B-folder import the_module`. In this case, the module name is `B-folder.the_module`. This gets put into the YAML file, as you can see.

In B, I'm assuming that you're just importing the_module internally, with something like `import the_module`. In this case, the module name is `the_module`. That's not the same as `B-folder.the_module`, which is why you get the error. If you instead imported in B using `from B-folder import the_module` or `import B-folder.the_module`, even though you're in the same folder, it should solve the problem.